# Does Kaplansky's Zero Divisor Conjecture hold valid for (torsion-free) residually finite groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Kaplansky's Zero Divisor Conjecture states that the group algebra $KG$ has no zero divisor for any field $K$ and any torsion-free group $G$.

Does Kaplansky's Zero Divisor Conjecture hold valid whenever $G$ is a torsion-free residually finite?

The same question for Idempotent conjecture may be proposed.

Comment: Both conjectures are open for any torsion-free finite-index subgroup of $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$.

Comment: @YCor: Could you please kindly give a reference for the being open of   the case torsion-free finite-index subgroups of $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reference, I just know that currents known results do not cover this case (for instance, $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is not virtually left-orderable by Witte, Proc AMS 1994, and does not have the Haagerup Property by Kazhdan's theorem).

Comment: The idempotent conjecture is known to be true for all lattices in conected Lie groups --- see http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0876 (for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ this was known before, the paper contains lots of further references).